# How the `IsAuthenticated` property gets true value by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In the Page_Load event handler function, I tried the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Write("Hello World");
        }
    }
```

And It works ! the browser shows Hello World ! but how the `IsAuthenticated` property gets true value by default?

My web.config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="arsenicDesktopConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=arsenicDesktop;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <!--LOCAL APPLICATION SETTINGS-->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Accounts_SettingsFile" value="C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\UserAuthenticationSystem\Config\Accounts.Config"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: are you using windows authentication?

Comment: I am afraid I dont know. I simply chose to create a new ASP.NET empty website. I dont know whether it is windows or form authentication specified.

Comment: look I've edited my question and attached my web.config file, there is no specification there.

Comment: The default authentication mode is `Windows`. If there is no `<authentication />` node in your config file, Windows authentication is automatically used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the `<authentication />` element's mode property; if Windows, it will be set to true as it uses the current windows user; if forms, then you have to be logged in.

A guide to setting up forms authentication is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Comment: look I've edited my question and attached my web.config file, there is no specification there.

Comment: @BNL My question is why it doesn't need specification in my web.config ?

Comment: ASP.NET uses Windows authentication by default, which means it will use the Identity that IIS uses (or you if you're running locally): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/907hb5w9(v=vs.100)

Comment: @D Stanley that means isAuthenticated will always be true by default ?

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud no specification means windows authentication, means it finds your windows ID which is a valid user and an authenticated user.  Set <authentication mode="forms" /> and setup your application to use the membership API to use the in-built forms authentication approach.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

somewhere within the `<system.web>` section, like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <system.web>
</configuration>
```

Updating your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="arsenicDesktopConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=arsenicDesktop;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    </system.web>
    <!--LOCAL APPLICATION SETTINGS-->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Accounts_SettingsFile" value="C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\UserAuthenticationSystem\Config\Accounts.Config"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```